# How to improve order by performance with joins in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-order-by, inner-join

I am working on a social network tracking application. Even joins works fine with proper indexing. But when I add the order by clause the total query takes 100 times longer time to execute. The following query I used to get the twitter_users without order by clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `tracked_twitter`.id
FROM tracked_twitter
INNER JOIN  `twitter_content` ON  `tracked_twitter`.`id` = `twitter_content`.`tracked_twitter_id` 
INNER JOIN  `tracker_twitter_content` ON  `twitter_content`.`id` = `tracker_twitter_content`.`twitter_content_id` 
AND  `tracker_twitter_content`.`tracker_id` =  '88'
LIMIT 20
```

Showing rows 0 - 19 (20 total, Query took 0.0714 sec)

But when I add order by clause ( on indexed column )

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `tracked_twitter`.id
FROM tracked_twitter
INNER JOIN  `twitter_content` ON  `tracked_twitter`.`id` =  `twitter_content`.`tracked_twitter_id` 
INNER JOIN  `tracker_twitter_content` ON  `twitter_content`.`id` =  `tracker_twitter_content`.`twitter_content_id` 
AND  `tracker_twitter_content`.`tracker_id` =  '88'
ORDER BY tracked_twitter.followers_count DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Showing rows 0 - 19 (20 total, Query took 13.4636 sec)

EXPLAIN
[image]

When I implement the order by clause in its table alone it doesn't take much time

```
SELECT * FROM `tracked_twitter` WHERE 1 order by `followers_count` desc limit 20
```

Showing rows 0 - 19 (20 total, Query took 0.0711 sec) [followers_count: 68236387 - 10525612]

The table creation query as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tracked_twitter` (
    `id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `handle` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `location` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    `profile_image` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `followers_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `is_influencer` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `gender` enum('Male','Female','Other') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci 
     DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `followers_count` (`followers_count`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

So join didn't slow the query and order by working well when I execute it on its table. So how can I improve performance?

**UPDATE 1**

@GordonLinoff method solves if i only need the result set from parent table. What f I want to know the number tweets per person (count of twitter_content which match the tracked_twitter table). How can I modify it? And if I want to have math functions on tweet content how do I do it ??

```
SELECT  `tracked_twitter` . * , COUNT( * ) AS twitterContentCount, retweet_count + favourite_count + reply_count AS engagement
FROM  `tracked_twitter` 
INNER JOIN  `twitter_content` ON  `tracked_twitter`.`id` =  `twitter_content`.`tracked_twitter_id` 
INNER JOIN  `tracker_twitter_content` ON  `twitter_content`.`id` =  `tracker_twitter_content`.`twitter_content_id` 
WHERE  `is_influencer` !=  '1'
AND  `tracker_twitter_content`.`tracker_id` =  '88'
AND  `tracked_twitter_id` !=  '0'
GROUP BY  `tracked_twitter`.`id` 
ORDER BY twitterContentCount DESC 
LIMIT 20 
OFFSET 0
```

Comment: How long does the unordered query take if you remove the `LIMIT`-clause? `LIMIT` in an unordered result-set basically means "get me some 20 records that match my criteria" while in an ordered result it means "get me the first 20 records that match my criteria" and that basically means you have to indentify all of them.

Comment: What's output of `EXPLAIN` on the query?

Comment: @raina77ow I added explain picture in question

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the other two tables.  It sounds like you are missing `INDEX(tracker_id)`.  See this for how to make many:many efficient:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try getting rid of the `distinct`.  That is a performance killer.  I'm not sure why your first query works quickly; perhaps MySQL is smart enough to optimize it away.

I would try:

```
SELECT tt.id
FROM tracked_twitter tt
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM twitter_content tc INNER JOIN  
                   tracker_twitter_content ttc
                   ON  tc.id =  ttc.twitter_content_id
              WHERE  ttc.tracker_id =  88 AND
                     tt.id =  tc.tracked_twitter_id
             )
ORDER BY tt.followers_count DESC ;
```

For this version, you want indexes on:  `tracked_twitter(followers_count, id)`, `twitter_content(tracked_twitter_id, id)`, and
`tracker_twitter_content(twitter_content_id, tracker_id)`.

Comment: It's working perfectly, and order by clause didn't slow the query execution (20 total, Query took 0.0707 sec) also. I will be glad if you explain the query. So that I will get the knowledge on this approach. And if you have any reference link to read about these approaches, it will be useful. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I suppose the first query works quickly because MySQL knows it only has to collect 20 distinct records from an unordered set, which probably comes from a low number of rows (let's say more than 20 but less than a thousand). Getting the first 20 distinct from an ordered set of millions of entries will be a lot slower - distinct's either a bit of a red herring and it's the orderby that is taking the time, or maybe MySQL is being dumb enough to not only order, but then also distinct millions of rows before returning just 20

Comment: @CaiusJard . . . Actually, I think MySQL can use the index on the `id` to prevent duplicates -- it is just reading the index in order.  With an explicit `ORDER BY`, that is not possible.

Comment: Try this query for ids other than 88; you may find that it has inconsistent performance.

Comment: I have a small problem with this query. If I want to know the number tweets per person (count of twitter_content which match the tracked_twitter table). How can I modify it? And if I want to have math functions on tweet content how do I do it ?? @GordonLinoff. I updated the question with the sample query.

Comment: @Tamizharasan . .. You would then have another question.  A new question should be asked as a question, rather than as a comment.

Comment: @GordonLinoff https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46069997/how-to-improve-query-performance-with-order-by-group-by-and-joins

Answer (score 1):

Parent table keep on bracket with limit

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `tracked_twitter`.id FROM
(SELECT id,followers_count  FROM tracked_twitter ORDER BY followers_count DESC 
LIMIT 20) AS tracked_twitter
INNER JOIN  `twitter_content` ON  `tracked_twitter`.`id` =  `twitter_content`.`tracked_twitter_id` 
INNER JOIN  `tracker_twitter_content` ON  `twitter_content`.`id` =  `tracker_twitter_content`.`twitter_content_id` 
AND  `tracker_twitter_content`.`tracker_id` =  '88'
ORDER BY tracked_twitter.followers_count DESC
```

Comment: It can't be the answer. because you didn't consider other tables constraint in order by clause. So it takes just 20 records from the parent table and joins with others. I got only two rows when I execute the query.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that even that you have relatively few rows, you use `varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` as a primary key (instead of integers) and hence as the foreign key in other tables. The same problem, I suspect, is with `twitter_content.id`. This causes a lot of long string comparisons and reserving a lot of extra memory for the temporary tables.

Concerning the query itself, yes, it should be a query that walks along the `followers_count` index and checks the condition for the related tables. This could be done as Gordon Linoff suggested, or by using index hints.