# How to improve query performance with order by, group by and joins

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-order-by, inner-join

I Had a problem with order by when joins multiple tables which have millions of data. But I got solution as instead of join with distinct use of EXISTS will improve performance from the following question

[How to improve order by performance with joins in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053284/how-to-improve-order-by-performance-with-joins-in-mysql)

```
SELECT
   `tracked_twitter` . *,
   COUNT( * ) AS twitterContentCount,
   retweet_count + favourite_count + reply_count AS engagement 
FROM
   `tracked_twitter` 
   INNER JOIN
      `twitter_content` 
      ON `tracked_twitter`.`id` = `twitter_content`.`tracked_twitter_id` 
   INNER JOIN
      `tracker_twitter_content` 
      ON `twitter_content`.`id` = `tracker_twitter_content`.`twitter_content_id` 
WHERE
   `tracker_twitter_content`.`tracker_id` = '88'
GROUP BY
   `tracked_twitter`.`id` 
ORDER BY
   twitterContentCount DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

But that method solves if I only need the result set from the parent table. What if, I want to execute grouped count and other math functions in other than parent table. I wrote a query that solves my criteria, but it takes 20 sec to execute. How can I optimize it ??.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and return unpredictable data with older versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: Please qualify all your column names.  What table does `is_influencer` come from?  `tracked_twitter_id` ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just edited the where condition, those two conditions added mistakenly.

Comment: 1. This doesn't parse, you have `where and`. 2. You are asking about a query you haven't even given. Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Given the query is already fairly simple the options I'd look in to are ...

- Execution plan (to find any missing indexes you could add)
- caching (to ensure SQL already has all the data in ram)
- de-normalisation (to turn the query in to flat select)
- cache the data in the application (so you could use something like PLINQ on it)
- Use a ram based store (redis, elastic)
- File group adjustments (physically move the db to faster discs)
- Partition your tables (to spread the raw data over multiple physical discs)

The further you go down this list the more involved the solutions become.
I guess it depends how fast you need the query to be and how much you need your solution to scale.